# how to send jsonObject post request in volley library? am using php for the server side

Tags: php, android, json

**Code:-**

it sends a `JsonObject` `POST` request to the server with in the log in user id
and everything is fine but the `POST` request is not work

```
sharedPreferences = getActivity ().getSharedPreferences ( MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
            final String logedUserId = sharedPreferences.getString ( usersId, "" );
            Map<String, String> postParams= new HashMap<String, String> ();
            postParams.put ( "userId", logedUserId );
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest ( Request.Method.POST, getUrl (),new JSONObject ( postParams), new Response.Listener<JSONObject> () {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    VolleyError.setVisibility ( View.GONE );
                    NewsList = parseJSONResponse ( response );
                    adapterNews.setNewsList ( NewsList );

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener () {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyError.setVisibility ( View.VISIBLE );
                    if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        VolleyError.setText ( R.string.error_timeout );

                    } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                        VolleyError.setText ( R.string.Auth_Fail_Error );

                    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                        VolleyError.setText ( R.string.Server_Error );

                    } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        VolleyError.setText ( R.string.Network_Error );

                    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                        VolleyError.setText ( R.string.Parse_Error );

                    }

                }
            } ){
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError{
                    HashMap<String, String> headers= new HashMap<> (  );
                    headers.put ( "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    return headers;
                }
            };
            VolleySingleton.getInstance ( getActivity () ).addToRequestqueue ( request, "UserId" );
```

**Server Response**

```
    {
      "NEWS": Array[10][
        {
          "News_id": "57",
          "News_Host_Id": "1",
          "News_Host_Agent": "AppFactory",
          "News_Post_Date": "2017-10-27",
          "News_Title": "Amazing fashion blog",
          "News_Descriptions": "Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
          "News_image": "http://10.0.2.2:81/file/server-side/upload/24610.jpg"
        },
        {
          "News_id": "57",
          "News_Host_Id": "1",
          "News_Host_Agent": "Computer Scince",
          "News_Post_Date": "2017-10-27",
          "News_Title": "Amazing fashion blog",
          "News_Descriptions": "Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
          "News_image": "http://10.0.2.2:81/file/server-side/upload/24610.jpg"
        }
]
}
```

when user send post request the server side code will authenticate the user id if the user subscribe for the news channel and give `JSON` result like the above

Answer (score 0):

```
private void login() {

    final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("email", "tu@tu.in");
        jsonObject.put("password", "123456");
        jsonObject.put("login_by", "manual");
        jsonObject.put("device_type", "android");
        jsonObject.put("device_token", "fz_swyQo2-E:APA91bE3VVfHEPGAghrKaHw46FK3g3JUxsqEJJkPGKXIjnjrLgbPZyGkyfdg5OaaayiEyGCmZKkGyoqoxZ-KlXMUhrNDHZvS1j68oq64uQ8Thm9SrZ78wpblTBnUczHAXXLRSGk7PQMo");
        jsonObject.put("app_version", "1.3.1");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "JSONException : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    String url = "https://Demo.com/userslogin.php";

    final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
            url, jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "response : " + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    pDialog.hide();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "VolleyError : " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return params;
        }
    };

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}
```

Comment: can you tell me whats wrong with my code? just for the future

Comment: i think the part where you are converting map to jsonobjec .

Comment: it doesnt post the user id